# Is there a way to specify custom main.rs/lib.rs for Rust app development?

Tags: rust, config, program-entry-point, lib

Perhaps use foo.rs/bar.rs instead of the default main/lib package root file?

How to config it?

Answer (score 3):

For a library, set `[lib].path`:

```ini
[lib]
path = "src/bar.rs"
```

For a binary, set `[[bin]].path`:

```ini
[[bin]]
name = "foo"
path = "src/foo.rs"
```